# Scrolling in a circle shape with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a list of items to scroll as if they were in a circle, but they don't fit one after the other because there's too many of them. Much like a rotary phone, I have made a quick and dirty diagram to help better illustrate it

[image]

This has to work on mobile, so based on my experience it would be much smoother using CSS transforms. [This example](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/1760283/593fa8bf024ccdddf2fe67826aece0b420c9d60e) looks promising, though I can't figure out how to make use of it while scrolling

EDIT:
I've tried to do it using JS and listening for scroll events, but I feel like there's a better solution. I have tried [ScrollPath](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/) and I liked it, but sadly it doesn't work on mobile.

2nd EDIT to try to remove the hold:
I have spent an hour trying to figure out how to do this without too much JS overhead. Many times I've discovered plugins too late after I have finished implementing my own solution. I am not asking for a snippet of code to copy and paste, but for the best approach the community can come up with, in plain English. Sorry if this question sounds like a dumb assignment from the university, but it's a hobby project at home and I've tried a couple of approaches with javascript, I will post the code later if requested, but what it basically did was fire an event on every scroll event and calculate all items X position according to its offset with the top. It felt a little laggy on mobile phones, and that is why I asked for this.

Comment: have you actually attempted anything?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to bust the old trigonometry book and do a little sin/cos. Here's the simplest example i could come up with. Proof is in the puddin' http://jsfiddle.net/67zMe/5/

**HTML:** Create a list of item to place on a circle.

```
<ul id="circle-list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:** Lay some ground-work CSS.

```
#circle-list
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    border:solid 2px #ccc;
    left:50%;
    top:20px;
    margin-left:-150px;
}

#circle-list li
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background:#ccc;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#666;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;      
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    /** offset top and left half the item's width so that as we position the items, it is from their center point. **/
    margin:-15px 0 0 -15px;
}
```

**JS:** Here's where the magic happens. Javascript to the rescue.

```
// Get degrees between each item, based on total items.
var angleSteps = 360 / $('#circle-list li').length;
// base angle to increment, which will rotate entire list.
var baseAngle = 0;
// center of the circle, relative to parent <ul>
var center = 150;
// distance to place each item from the center
var distance = 100;

function updateListPositions()
{
    // loop through each list item and place it on the circle based on it's angle
    $('#circle-list li').each(function(index, element)
       {
           var angle = baseAngle + (index * angleSteps);
           var x = distance * Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
           var y = distance * Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
           $(element).css({left:center+x, top:center+y});
       });
}

// set a timer to continually increment the base angle, which rotates the circle.
// this could easily be changed to increment the circle based on scroll delta

var stepInterval = setInterval(stepAngle, 25);

function stepAngle()
{
    baseAngle++;
    // update position as base angle changes
    updateListPositions();
}
```

Comment: It indeed looks good, but it doesn't handle, let's say, a thousand items without overcrowding the circle. The idea is to make them appear from one side and disappear from the other

Comment: It will, but not without making the circle bigger or the objects smaller (or both). It's not meant to be an out of the box solution, just to show you how to rotate objects in a circle.